# Tensor Notation

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, tensor

Is it possible to represent the following tensor in pdf by TeX.

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Did you look at the `tensor` package?

Comment: `$T^{abcd}{}_{efgh}{}^{ijkl}{}_{mnop}$`?

Comment: @egreg You're a lightning bolt :-)

Comment: Thank you @JouleV !! Your code is the one what I want. Thank you.

Comment: @CamfordOxbridge Here you find the tensor package: http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tensor/tensor.pdf